# Git remove --cached by TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have updated my `.gitignore` file and now I want to update the index. I want to execute `git rm --cached` command. But how can I do it by TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click that file, choose TortoiseGit -> Delete (keep local).
This does `git rm --cached`.