# How not to display the .class in git

Tags: git, gitignore, git-status

I don't want to display `.class` files when executing `git status`.

I created a file named `.gitignore` and entered the `.class` in the file but nothing happened.

What is the best way to prevent the `.class` file from being displayed when you execute `git status` command?

Comment: That’s the correct way to do it. Can you post the contents of your `.gitignore`?

Comment: And the output from `git status`?

Comment: the content of my .git ignore is just  ***.class**

Answer (score 53):

Make sure your .class files were not *already* added to the index.
You would need to `git rm -r --cached path/to/.classfiles/` those files first.
(they will still be on the disk, but no longer part of the git index, and will be ignored by the `git status`)

If you don't want any `.class` file versioned (but you didn't include them in the `.gitignore` initially), as [Michal Stefanow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775359/michal-stefanow) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251253/how-not-to-display-the-class-in-git/14252398?noredirect=1#comment48088675_14252398) below:

```
git rm -r --cached *.class
```

[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271985/mark) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251253/how-not-to-display-the-class-in-git/14252398#comment117316972_14252398):

> For Windows TortoiseGit users like me, follow the instructions in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292047/6309) to do the git in the GUI
>
> Right click that file, choose TortoiseGit -> Delete (keep local).
> This does `git rm --cached`.

Comment: ```path/to/.classfiles/``` or simply ```git rm -r --cached *.class``` to remove them all

Comment: @MichalStefanow Indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Just a convenience, usually we want to exclude all ```class``` files, I cannot think of any case where some of them should be kept in source control.

Comment: @MichalStefanow I agree. This `git rm` command is usually done when you forgot to include `.class` in the `.gitignore`, and added by mistake some `.class` files to the index.

Comment: For Windows TortoiseGit users like me, follow the instructions in this related post to do the git in the GUI - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12292047/271985

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 15):

You probably actually want to add `*.class` into your `.gitignore` file, not `.class` - the former will match any class file (because of the wildcard `*`), whereas the latter only matches a file named exactly `.class`.

Comment: Did you already `git add` the class files in the past? If so, you'll have to manually untrack them before `.gitignore` will do anything.

Comment: how to untrack .class files?

Comment: `git rm --cached <path to class file>`, then commit.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file named ./gitignore in your directory and add the following lines in that:

```
target/
bin/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
.nb-gradle/
target/
```

Comment: This simply doesn't work.