# Git is adding my desktop icon how to to remove

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Installed [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), then I accidentally pressed the menu when I am doing right click on my desktop I don't know which one in the menu I pressed, then my desktop refreshes and all my desktop icon have now blue plus icon. How can I remove this ? Looks like my icon desktop will be added to my github repository if I will do commit.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: The [manual](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-ignore.html) is telling you how to ignore files. Additionally you could add those file to your [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) manually.

Comment: Does right-clicking on any of these files with "blue plus icon" allow any **revert / undo-add** TortoiseGit menu option?

Comment: Sounds/looks like you probably accidentally initialized your desktop as a git repository. If you didn't mean to do that, you can delete the hidden `.git` directory on your desktop to undo it.  You'll need to temporarily change your settings in control panel to show hidden dirs/files to see it in explorer.  If you don't see it there, check its parent directories

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git remove --cached by Tortoise Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426895/git-remove-cached-by-tortoise-git)

Answer (score 0):

To remove staged files

```
git rm --cached
```

Or in TortoiseGit you may use "delete (keep local)"

This will unstage all changes, you have to stage the relevant files again.

This is not a duplicate but may relate to [Git remove --cached by Tortoise Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426895/git-remove-cached-by-tortoise-git) (answer by @linquize)